# How do I set permissions for POST requests in Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got two Django models that are linked like this:

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='objects')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class ChildModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, related_name='child_objects')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Now, when making ViewSet for child model, I want it to be created only if its parent was created by the same user that is creating child instance. The permission class that I'm including into my `ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet)` looks like this:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.parent.creator == request.user
```

This seems to work just fine when i use `PATCH` method, but `POST` methods don't seem to notice this permission class even when I explicitly set `return False` for `POST` method.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: it doesn't work for `PATCH` method. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your urls and views, but please look at the default methods implemented in `BasePermission` which you inherit:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    """
    Return `True` if permission is granted, `False` otherwise.
    """
    return True

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    """
    Return `True` if permission is granted, `False` otherwise.
    """
    return True
```

For `PATCH` you're working with an object which already exists, and you go into the custom method that you've overridden - OK!  For `POST`, you may be hooking into the other one, because you're creating a new object.

So, try implementing `has_permission` in your derived class.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674039/wim) for providing me with a hint to an answer!

The reason why my permission didn't work with `POST` requests is, indeed, that the object has not yet been created and so I should use `has_permission` in my permission class. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    user_id = getattr(request.user, 'id')
    parent_id = request.data['parent']
    if parent_id is not None:
        parent_obj = ParentModel.objects.get(id=parent_id)
        serialized = ParentSerializer(association)
        return user_id == serialized.data['creator']
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I managed to tweak this for something I'm doing.

Comment: @Oleh Omelchenko, where does `data['parent']` in `parent_id = request.data['parent']` come from? I receive a `WSGIRequest does not have attribute 'data'` error. Are you setting the attribute on the request?